# Uncaught Syntax Error: Missing ) after argument

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I looked through other solutions to this same question, but I could not fix my error.

The code in question...

```
function checkCookie() {
var user=getCookie("username");
if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome back " + user "!"); // Error right here
} else {
   user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
   if (user != "" && user != null) {
       setCookie("username", user, 30);
  }
}
}
```

I get the error at line 36 (commented)

Uncaught error is displayed when I check developer tools. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Add `+` in  after `user` variable like this => `alert("Welcome back " + user+"!");`

Comment: Thank you, facepalming so hard after missing something so simple.

Comment: If one of these answers answered your question, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `+`

```
alert("Welcome back " + user + "!");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Your sting is invalid, you missed a `+`

```
alert("Welcome back " + user + "!"); // The second +
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with pluses and quotation marks you could try [string templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var user = "John";
console.log(`Welcome back ${user}!`);
```